# Visualization (even locally) of graphs with given infinite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, soft-question

I want to give a lecture about Frucht theorem (and its generalization) which state that: for each finite group $G$, there is at least one finite graph $\Gamma$ such that $Aut(\Gamma)\cong G$. For each finite group, it is not difficult to present pictorially the respective graph, since it is sufficient we work with Cayley color graph of the group $G$ and replace the edges with some suitable trees.

But, Sabidussi ("Graphs with Given Infinite Group", 1959) showed that if the group $G$ is infinite, then the statement is true and there is an infinite graph $\Gamma$ such that $Aut(\Gamma)\cong G$.

I have three groups $SU(2)$, $SO(3)$ and $SU(3)$, which I need to present their related graphs pictorially. Actually, it is sufficient I can show locally these graphs. Is there any way that I can give some pictures of the related graphs of these groups? Actually, I do not know what can be their graphs.

Thanks for any guidance and help.